# Perform SUM of COUNTS DISTINCT of multiple columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

```
COUNT(DISTINCT invoiceType1)` AS `#invoices2`, 
COUNT(DISTINCT invoiceType2)` AS `#invoices2`,
```

Is there a way to add these two counts together? Though they are all `DISTINCT` I am unsure of if it will behave correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: how jquery tag here?

Comment: You title should be your question, not some statement in it.

Comment: @Piyush because jQuery is the answer to everything.

Comment: @bluefeet Reminds me of the post where someone asked how to use JavaScript to add two numbers and was told to use JQuery.

Comment: @Piyush I wrongly tagged jquery while I wanted to tag query. Sorry my screen text was too darn small...

Answer (score 0):

try this, just add these two count using '+' operator

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT invoiceType1) AS #invoices1, 
COUNT(DISTINCT invoiceType2) AS #invoices2, 
COUNT(DISTINCT invoiceType1) + COUNT(DISTINCT invoiceType2) AS #totalinvoicescount
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Yeah, I commented, then figured I could edit it myself :P Thanks, though.